# How do I use Nested For Loop in this question? (Without Arrays)

Tags: java

The question is from the Nested For Loops chapter, so I assume that I should use Nested For Loops for this.

In an entrance examination, students have answered English, Maths and Science papers. Write a program to calculate and display average marks obtained by all the students. Take number of students appeared and marks obtained in all three subjects by every student along with the name as inputs.

And this is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
class average
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
    int i,j,m,s,e,sum;
    String name;
    double a;
    System.out.println("Enter number of students that appeared");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name");
        name = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter marks obtained in English");
        e = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter marks obtained in Maths");
        m = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter marks obtained in Science");
        s = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        sum = e + m + s;
        a = sum/3.0;
        System.out.println("Average Marks = "+a);
    }
}
}
```

So how do I exactly use Nested For Loop with this? Have I misunderstood the question? If so, then what should I do?

Comment: You don't need a *nested* loop here. Maybe  you can use a *collection* or an *array* to store the information of all the students.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question requiring you to use a nested loop.

Comment: @NicholasK Well I have not yet learnt of those. The chapter in which this question is given is Nested For Loops, so I assume that I should use a Nested For Loop.

Comment: @Bjarke Well I have not yet learnt of those. The chapter in which this question is given is Nested For Loops, so I assume that I should use a Nested For Loop.

Comment: @CodeLearner - That does seem like a reasonable assumption. :-) I'd use the "edit" link to add that information to the question.

Comment: Also curious here, what's wrong with you current code? It does find the average of each student and displays it. Or do you want to find the average by *each* subject? Specifically what *average* do you want to calculate?

Comment: @NicholasK The only problem in here is as stated, not being able to use Nested For Loop, and I assume I should use Nested For Loop as this question is from the chapter of Nested For Loops.

Comment: Well if you have achieved the target without nested for-loops, then you don't need it I guess.

Comment: @NicholasK Well I just assumed that I _need_ to use Nested For Loop because its from that chapter. If I don't need to use it, then I've got no problems in all honesty.

Comment: I think perhaps you are imagining the wrong interaction. I think what the exercise meant was an interaction like this "Enter number of students" (`8`). "Enter name" (`Andrew`). "Enter marks in all three subjects" (`89 56 72`). This means you have to *loop* over the three marks to sum them up. Imagine if you had 20 subjects. Would you still put the marks in 20 different variables?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use nested loop in the code snippet. You should split it with two parts: receive student's data and pring student's data.

First, define a class that represents student's score:

```
public final class StudentScore {

    private final String name;
    private final int scoreEnglish;
    private final int scoreMaths;
    private final int scoreScience;
    // TODO a put this parameter hered, but probably it's is better to calculate id every time when required
    private final double avg;

    public StudentScore(String name, int scoreEnglish, int scoreMaths, int scoreScience) {
        this.name = name;
        this.scoreEnglish = scoreEnglish;
        this.scoreMaths = scoreMaths;
        this.scoreScience = scoreScience;
        avg = (scoreEnglish + scoreEnglish + scoreEnglish) / 3.;
    }

    // getters
}
```

Second, define a method that use `Scanner` (this is more useful that `InputStreamReadr` when working with console) to receive amount of students and student's data:

```
private static List<StudentScore> getStudentsScore() {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Enter number of students that appeared: ");
        int total = scan.nextInt();

        List<StudentScore> studentScores = new ArrayList<>(total);

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            String name = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter marks obtained in English: ");
            int scoreEnglish = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter marks obtained in Maths: ");
            int scoreMaths = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter marks obtained in Science");
            int scoreScience = scan.nextInt();

            studentScores.add(new StudentScore(name, scoreEnglish, scoreMaths, scoreScience));
        }

        return studentScores;
    }
}
```

Third, all you left to do is just receive list of student's data and pring required parameters:

```
List<StudentScore> studentScores = getStudentsScore();
studentScores.forEach(studentScore -> System.out.format("Average Marks for student '%s' is '%.2f'\n", studentScore.getName(), studentScore.getAvg()));
```

**P.S.**

It is not pretty clear what exaclty average score should you calculate, but when you receive `List<StudentScore> studentScores`, you can calculate all you need.